# laravelbook/ardent 3.6.0 not getting installed in Laravel 7.15.0

Tags: laravel-7, ardent

I have one Laravel 4.2 project which uses laravelbook/ardent and needs to updated to newest Laravel Version. But the problem is that laravelbook/ardent doesn't get installed and giving following error upon installation.

[image]

Now I don't know how to deal with this. Which Laravel version supports laravelbook/ardent?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know 3.6.0 is the last Ardent version and it matches with Laravel 5.1 version (since 3.0.0, check here https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent/releases).
You can eventually try pushing yourself a bit further with Laravel versions but, of course, you have to try.
I'm not sure I would update something to an already-old framework building my models around an abandoned plugin...